# Mallows distribution: unimodality and mean inversion number — reference request

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, reference-request, permutations

Under the Mallows distribution, in which each permutation $\pi\in S_n$ is weighted by $q^{\mathrm{inv}(\pi)}$ for some $q>0$, where $\mathrm{inv}(\pi)$ denotes the number of inversions in $\pi$, the probability of a permutation $\pi$ with $k$ inversions is
$$
\mathbb{P}\big[\mathrm{Mallows}(q)=\pi\big] \;=\; \frac{q^k(1-q)^n}{\prod_{j=1}^n(1-q^j)}.
$$
Is there a standard reference for the result that this rational function is unimodal (for any valid $k$)?

Also, is there a reference in which the value of the expected number of inversions
$
\mathbb{E}\big[\mathrm{inv}(\mathrm{Mallows}(q))\big]
$
is determined/discussed?

Answer (score 1):

The expected number of inversions doesn't look too bad to me. Write

$$f(q) = (n)!_q = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1 - q^i}{1 - q} = \sum_{\pi \in S_n} q^{\text{inv}(\pi)}$$

for the [$q$-factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-analog). Then the expected number of inversions is just $q \frac{f'(q)}{f(q)}$. This is essentially the logarithmic derivative, which we can compute by writing

$$\log f(q) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \log (1 - q^i) - \log (1 - q) \right)$$

which gives

$$\frac{d}{dq} \log f(q) = \frac{f'(q)}{f(q)} = \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{1}{1 - q} - \frac{iq^{i-1}}{1 - q^i} \right)$$

and hence

$$\mathbb{E}(\text{inv}) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{q}{1-q} - \frac{iq^i}{1 - q^i} \right).$$

Alternatively, without denominators, writing $\frac{1 - q^i}{1 - q} = 1 + q + \dots + q^{i-1}$ gives

$$\mathbb{E}(\text{inv}) = q \frac{f'(q)}{f(q)} = \sum_{i=1}^n q \frac{1 + 2q + \dots + (i-1)q^{i-2}}{1 + q + \dots + q^{i-1}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The second question is answered by Propositions 1.2 & 1.3 *in* Ross G. Pinsky, [Comparing the inversion statistic for distribution-biased and distribution-shifted permutations with the geometric and the GEM distributions](https://alea.impa.br/articles/v19/19-09.pdf), *ALEA Lat. Am. J. Probab. Math. Stat.*, 19(1):209–229, 2022.

We have
$$
  \mathbb{E}\big[ \mathrm{inv}(\mathrm{Mallows}(q))\big] 
  \;\sim\;
  \begin{cases}
  \frac{q}{1-q} n, & \text{if $\;1-q \gg n^{-1}$}, \\[5pt]
  c(\alpha)n^2, & \text{if $\;1-q \sim {\alpha}n^{-1}$}, \\[5pt]
  \frac14 n^2, & \text{if $\;1-q \ll n^{-1}$},
  \end{cases}
  $$
where $c(\alpha) = \frac1{\alpha} - \frac1{\alpha^2}\mathrm{Li}_2(1-e^{-\alpha})$ satisfies $\lim\limits_{\alpha\to0}c(\alpha)=\frac14$ and, for large $\alpha$, $c(\alpha) \sim 1/\alpha$.